# Understanding Unusual SQL Queries in AWS Performance Insights with Dropwizard and MySQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, amazon-rds, database-performance, jdbi

**Context**:

I've observed some unexpected SQL queries appearing as top entries in AWS Performance Insights, and I'm trying to understand their origin and impact.

**Details**:

The queries in question are:

1. `SELECT @@SESSION.transaction_read_only`
2. `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = ?`
3. `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT = DEFAULT`

These queries are consistently showing up as the top three queries in AWS Performance Insights, but they are not explicitly written in my application's code. I'm using InnoDB with MySQL.

**What I've Tried**:

- I've reviewed my application's code and configuration files, but I couldn't find any direct references to these queries.
- I've checked the Maven dependency tree and confirmed that my application is using Tomcat's JDBC connection pool (`org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:jar:9.0.68`).
- I've considered the possibility that these queries might be related to the JDBC driver or JDBI's interaction with the database, but I'm not sure how to confirm this.

**Question**:

- Can anyone help me understand why these specific SQL queries are appearing in AWS Performance Insights?
- Are these queries a normal part of the JDBC driver or JDBI's operation with a MySQL database?
- If these queries are potentially impacting performance, what steps can I take to investigate further or mitigate this issue?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!